# Passing XML data and user from coldfusion page to .NET page

Tags: c#, xml, coldfusion, xss

I'd appreciate some input on this situation, I can't figure out the best way to do this.

I have some data that's being prepared for me in a ColdFusion app and in an IFrame within the CF app we want to display some graphs (not strictly an image, it's an entire page) being generated on the .NET side of things.  I'd like to pass XML data from the CF side to .NET as well as the user.

On the .NET side I'm putting the data in a session so the user can sift through it without the need to have it re-queried and re-passed from CF.

What I've tried:

- Generating XML with CF, putting it in a hidden form field, auto-submitting (with JS) a the form to the .NET side.

  - The issue I'm having  with this approach is the encoding being done on the form post.  The data has entries like `<entry data="hello &amp; goodbye">`.  It's an issue because it's being URL encdeded, Posted, and when I get it on the .NET side I get `<entry data="hello & goodbye">` which isn't properly formed XML.

What I'd like to avoid:

- An intermediary DB approach (dropping the data in a DB on CF, picking it up with .NET)  I'd like to only display what is passed to the page.  I have security concerns with the data, it's very sensitive.
- Passing the data to a webservice, returning a GUID, forwarding the user with a URL Parameter to access the passed in data.  I think that'd be risky if someone happened on a link to that data.  I can't take that risk.

I was thinking of passing the data with JSON, but I'm very unfamiliar with it.  Thoughts?

Thanks for your time folks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you're doing with the hidden field and decode it on the .net side of things:

```
string xmlStuff = Request.Form["thexml"];
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(xmlStuff, sw);
string decodedXMLStuff = sw.ToString();
```

That's all there is to it! From there you can load that xml string into an XDocument, or whatever you're using.

Comment: BTW -- with your security requirements, you do need to use form method POST and have HTTPS all around, of course. Frankly, I'm not sure why you don't like the DB idea... that's the most secure. Also, you can simply have the .net generate/pull the data it needs, rather than taking the extra step through CF.

Comment: Patches, thanks for the code.  I tried something similar and it encoded the whole string.  Let me try with your code verbatim.  Also, the reason I'm doing it this way is this is a simple add on to an existing legacy system.  I also don't want the responsibility of pulling all this data from the existing source systems (yes plural).  The data is already being pulled from the CF system, so they can pass it to me.  I'll let you know how it goes, cheers.

Comment: @Mark Rullo: Got ya. Legacy systems suck, don't they? :-) Incidentally, I do know you can pass unencoded xml in a POST variable. On one of my sites I've got a vendor pushing a xml data file at via HTTPS POST, and I don't have to do any decoding on my end. I just drop it directly into an XDocument. I have no idea how to make it happen in CF, however.

Comment: @Patches -- I tried your code verbatim and in an attribute, my characters are being decoded improperly.  For instance, I'm passing in <tag attrib="hello &lt; goodbye"> and after the HTMLDecode I'm getting <tag attrib="hello < goodbye">.  My issue is then passing this to XDocument.Parse, it's invalid XML.  Sigh.

Comment: @Patches, I prototyped this and went forward with this method because originally it DID work, my GOTCHA was the special character I got when I put this live.  DOH!  Test some more stupid...;(

Comment: @Mark Rullo: Yea, having two contexts for special characters can be tricky. One possibility if you must have that '<' in the data is to explictly Encode the data you save in those attributes, then let the CF encode the whole xml string as it is doing now. That way, the raw data you receive will have '&amp;lt;' (the '<' special character double encoded), which after the HtmlDecode will become '&lt;'